# Asymptotes Parallel to the axes.

Tags: functions, rational-functions

I need proof of this theorem.

Theorem: A straight line $y=c$ is an asymptote of a curve $f(x,y)=0$ iff $y - c$  is a factor of the co-efficient of the highest power of $x$ in $f (x,y)$.

Comment: Do you assume that $f(x,y)$ is a polynomial?

Comment: @Andrei , Yes  f(x,y) is a polynomial.

Comment: @Andrei can you provide me the proof?